# Extracting response and using While Controller to wait for response in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-5.0

All, I need additional assistance. I have tried researching and was using this following resource guide. https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-while-controller-jmeter

Problem

I need to Implement a way to wait for a specific Response from the server and record the time it takes from the start of the request to the end where I get a response of Complete in Jmeter. I have been looking at while controller and researching it.

Problem#1
If I add a while controller, my request failed because its adding multiple token. If I leave it without the while controller then it only gets 1 bearer token and it is able to submit a get request and get the response appropriately. I am suspecting there is a pre-procession somewhere else in my script that doing this...

[image]

Uses beanshell preprocesser to grab the token

```
sampler.getHeaderManager().add(new Header("Authorization","Bearer " + vars.get("BEARER")));
```

Problem #2

I have a GET Request to check the status of the request. Response in the BODY comes back as this json
"{"Status": "RECEIVED", "DllUrl": "", "Message": " "}"

I need it to continue checking for the status of COMPLETE……..also may need to check for failed as well

Was looking at regular Expression extractor to get the status and only stop until it finds COMPLETE status. That way I can measure time start and end time for completion. Any help and guidance will be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're adding a header and not removing the previous one therefore it adds another header on each iteration.

In fact you don't need to do any scripting for this, you can just define the header in the [HTTP Header Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-jmeters-http-header-manager):

[image]

With regards to extracting this `Status` value, it's better to do it using [JSON Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_Extractor) configured like:

[image]

Once done you can use the following [__jexl3() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__jexl3) to "wait" till the operation finishes:

```
${__jexl3("${status}" != "COMPLETE",)}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much Dmitri, wish there were a page that stackoverflow allows to contribute to developer who answers question ......i would definitely reward you for your contribution. This works....However, i need to figure out how to set a timeframe to wait for that response....and exit after a set amount of time...

Comment: found the info here: https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-while-controller-jmeter